# UIImagePickerController Image Type

Tags: ios7, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

My application allows a user to select an image from the devices camera roll. I would like to validate that the format of the selected image is either a PNG or JPG image.

is it possible to do this in the `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` delegate method?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do this in the delegate callback. As you may have noticed the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType` info dictionary key will return a "public.image" string back as the UTI, which isn't sufficient for your purpose. However, this can be done by using the url associated with the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` key in the info dictionary. For example, the implementation might look similar to the method below.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSURL *assetURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    NSString *extension = [assetURL pathExtension];
    CFStringRef imageUTI = (UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(__bridge CFStringRef)extension , NULL));

    if (UTTypeConformsTo(imageUTI, kUTTypeJPEG))
    {
        // Handle JPG
    }
    else if (UTTypeConformsTo(imageUTI, kUTTypePNG))
    {
        // Handle PNG
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled Image UTI: %@", imageUTI);
    }

    CFRelease(imageUTI);

    [self.imageView setImage:image];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

You'll also need to link against MobileCoreServices.framework and add a `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`